# Date-performance installation error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

When I try install the gem [date-performance](https://github.com/rtomayko/date-performance) with command `gem install date-performance`, I get this error:

```
date_performance.c:16:14: erro: static declaration of ‘rb_cRational’ follows non-static declaration
...
date_performance.c:365:3: aviso: ISO C90 forbids mixed declarations and code [-pedantic]
make: ** [date_performance.o] Erro 1
```

How to fix it?

**Udpate:**

The SO is Ubuntu and I use ruby 1.9

Follows the full error:

```
/home/vmlellis/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/bin/ruby extconf.rb
creating Makefile

make
compiling date_performance.c
date_performance.c:16:14: erro: static declaration of ‘rb_cRational’ follows non-static declaration
In file included from /home/vmlellis/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby.h:32:0,
                 from date_performance.c:9:
/home/vmlellis/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/ruby.h:1271:19: nota: previous declaration of ‘rb_cRational’ was here
date_performance.c: Na função ‘rb_date_new’:
date_performance.c:200:5: aviso: ISO C90 forbids mixed declarations and code [-pedantic]
date_performance.c:219:3: aviso: ISO C90 forbids mixed declarations and code [-pedantic]
date_performance.c: Na função ‘rb_date_strftime’:
date_performance.c:253:31: erro: ‘struct RString’ has no member named ‘ptr’
date_performance.c:254:29: erro: ‘struct RArray’ has no member named ‘ptr’
date_performance.c:268:30: erro: ‘struct RString’ has no member named ‘ptr’
date_performance.c:269:17: erro: ‘struct RString’ has no member named ‘len’
date_performance.c:277:30: erro: ‘struct RString’ has no member named ‘ptr’
date_performance.c:279:5: aviso: implicit declaration of function ‘bzero’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
date_performance.c:279:5: aviso: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘bzero’ [habilitado por padrão]
date_performance.c:284:23: erro: ‘struct RString’ has no member named ‘len’
date_performance.c: Na função ‘rb_date_strptime’:
date_performance.c:304:27: erro: ‘struct RString’ has no member named ‘ptr’
date_performance.c:305:27: erro: ‘struct RString’ has no member named ‘ptr’
date_performance.c:329:3: aviso: implicit declaration of function ‘strptime’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
date_performance.c: Na função ‘rb_date_compare’:
date_performance.c:350:3: aviso: ISO C90 forbids mixed declarations and code [-pedantic]
date_performance.c:353:5: aviso: comentários usando o estilo do C++ não são permitidos na ISO C90 [habilitado por padrão]
date_performance.c:353:5: aviso: (isso será relatado apenas uma vez por aquivo de entrada) [habilitado por padrão]
date_performance.c:365:3: aviso: ISO C90 forbids mixed declarations and code [-pedantic]
make: ** [date_performance.o] Erro 1
```

Comment: Please paste the full error. Also, what OS are you running?

Comment: Looks like `rb_cRational` is defined twice which could be a bug.,

Comment: I think that is only to ruby 1.8... I think that have improvements in Date's performance on ruby 1.9.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This gem is meant towards Ruby 1.8:

> This package adds some semblance of performance to Ruby 1.8's core
>   Date class using a combination of different techniques

It probably breaks in Ruby 1.9+ (Ruby isn't known for its forward compatibility..) and on the GitHub project page you can see it hasn't been updated for the last 4 years.

It won't work on your Ruby 1.9 Ubuntu installation.

Comment: Also important to note that Ruby 1.9.3 (if not earlier) has reimplemented Date in C as part of the standard library.